# SQL with condition

Tags: sql

if I have a sql statement like:

```
Select * from Order, OrderDetail 
where Order.ID = OrderDetail.OrderID and OrderDetail.Amount > 5
```

does it mean loop in all row when Order union with OrderDetail to find row meet condition Amount>5??

Please help me out.

My question is: if after join 2 tables, Do database loop in all rows created to find row meet condition.

Answer (score 4):

That query is joining the two tables via `Order.ID = OrderDetail.OrderID`. Whether it filters the resulting rows during or after I/O is up to the database. If you have an index on `Amount` it is conceivable that it will look up matching rows *then* join. Best to look at the `EXPLAIN` of the query.

But your query would be better expressed as:

```
select *
from Order
join OrderDetail on Order.ID = OrderDetail.OrderID
where OrderDetail.Amount > 5
```

This syntax makes it very clear what are the join criteria, and what are the row filtering conditions. And formatting it like this makes it easier to read too!

Usually, tables are given aliases, making it even easier to read:

```
Select *
from Order o
join OrderDetail od on o.ID = od.OrderID
where od.Amount > 5
```

Answer (score 3):

Rewritten as...

```
Select *
from Order, OrderDetail
where Order.ID = OrderDetail.OrderID
and OrderDetail.Amount > 5
```

...this query is using an old equijoin syntax (from Order, OrderDetail). This is the same as doing a join such as:

```
Select *
from Order
join OrderDetail ON ID=OrderId
where OrderDetail.Amount > 5
```

The way I would write this would probably be:

```
SELECT *
FROM Order o
JOIN OrderDetail od ON o.ID = od.OrderId AND od.Amount > 5
```

This query is getting all records from Order that have a matching record in OrderDetail with an Amount greater than 5.

---

You mentioned a UNION and I want to make the point that a JOIN and UNION are different things. A UNION will merge *rows* into one set whereas a JOIN will merge *columns* into a single set.